# How to retrieve f5 in bash

Tags: bash

Anyone advise how to fix this code? Problem with F5 in read. Please help..

```
read -sn3 KEY

case "$KEY" in
     $'\x1b[A') echo "press arrow up";;
     $'\x1b[B') echo "press arrow down";;
     $'???') echo "press key F5";;
esac
```

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
$ od -c <<< "<Ctrl-V><F5>"
0000000 033   [   1   5   ~  \n
0000006
```